# write on databases as out of rabbitmq

Tags: python, pika

Im new using rabbitmq.
Im doing a poc, first i write on queue rabbi_mq, then i want to write row by row on table named product in my database.  The table contains 3 columns (id, product_name, price)

How can i do it please?

**Below my code**

**Sender.py**

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body= 'x12, table, 30$')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body= 'x13, tv, 200$')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body= 'x14, desk, 100$')
print('published message')
connection.close()
```

**reciever.py**

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
```

Comment: What issues are you having reading from the channel?

Comment: @OneCricketeer there is no problem. Im just asking how to write on tables in the receiver.py.

Comment: Well, you first need to consume the channel, then open a database connection, parse out the data, then write the values like you would with any other variable. There's nothing specific to Pika library here that changes how you actually write to the database

Comment: Here's the documentation for a Postgres library if your problem is simply how to interact with the database https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html